# Input focus field then add class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, addclass

Okay here is the thing i have an input field with the class .cf-se-input. I want this field to be focused with jquery as soon as possible with document ready. Also if the field becomes focused either when the user clicks the input field or by jquery focus i want to addclass to a div with an id of #searchput. Here is the shakedown.

Page Load => .cf-se-input becomes focues =>

.cf-se-input becomes focused next code will fire => if .cf-se-input focused either when user clicks on field or when jquery automaticall focuses it on page load addClass .cfse_a to #searchput.

Going even further

This is my search box

```
<div id="searchput"> <input type="textarea" class="cf-se-input" /> </div>
```

I styled .cfse_a so that anything with that class has a blue border. 
In my case its not the input field with a blue border that i want i want the div of searchput to have a blue border but only when the input field is focused.

Now there are two ways that a field can be focused either by jquery or by hand. I want both to be covered. So if the user clicks the input and it becomes focused i still want to addClass to #searchput. Also if on page load jquery forces input field to be focused i still want #searchput to addClass .cfse_a on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$.focus()` method.  See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/focus/.

You can call `$('.cf-se-input').focus()` to make the focus move to your textarea.

You can call `$('.cf-se-input').focus(function() { alert('focused!'); });` from `$(document).ready` in order to execute some code when the textarea is focused.

Comment: i tried $('.cf-se-input').focus();    $('.cf-se-input').focus(function() { $('#searchput').addClass('cfse_a'); }); that is what i tried however on document ready the input field is focused however on focuessed addcalss doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user focused highlighted easiest way is to use just CSS

```
.inputElement:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #EC8937;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #EC8937;
}
```

if you can add another class to the element when Jquery document ready
you can get the input highlighted when initiating

but make sure you have a way of removing that class when focus is no longer needed or when user click on something else